# Добавит текст к ссылке php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть данная переменная

```
$description = "текст https://google.com текст";
```

Как я могу ссылку взять в тег `[link]` что бы получилось так:

```
$description = "текст [link]https://google.com[/link] текст";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$description = "текст https://google.com текст";
$description = preg_replace('~(https?://.*?)(\s|$)~', '[link]$1[/link]$2', $description);
var_dump($description);
```

Ищем начало ссылки в виде `https://` или `http://`. А конец - первый пробел после начала или конец строки

Comment: Так то оно проще, а если будет `https://kfdsmflk` ?

Comment: @Denis640Kb И что? Может еще доступность сервера проверять?

Comment: С чего вдруг такие нервы? Нет, доступность сервера проверять не обязательно. А строку, чтобы она была не просто текстом, а именно ссылкой - хорошо бы.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Какие нервы? Дайте определение, что такое ссылка? Вот такую ссылку `http://test.americanexpress` ваша регулярка выбросит, а тем не менее [.americanexpress](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/americanexpress.html) вполне валидный домен верхнего уровня

Comment: Это добавляется изменением одной цифры. Но ссылка проверяется, в отличие от Вашего варианта.

Answer (score 1):

Если на php, то простым образом можно так(Чтобы не писать регулярные выражения, так как ссылка может быть разной):

```php
$description = "текст https://google.com текст";

$new = explode(' ', $description);
$newline = '"'.$new[0].' [link]'.$new[1].'[link] '.$new[2].'"';

print_r($newline);
```

Вариант с регулярным выражением.

```php
$description = "текст https://google.com текст";

$new = preg_replace("^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www\.)?([A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]{1}[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9\-]*\.?)*\.{1}[A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9-]{2,8}(\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/])*)?^", '[link]$0[link]', $description);
print_r($new);
```

Comment: Неизвестно сколько будет слов и на каком месте будет стоять ссылка

Comment: @Владислав Самохин, Ссылка может быть любой длинны?

Comment: Верно, возможно делать поиск по http?

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, тогда в этом случае воспользоваться регулярными выражениями.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, Добавил вариант, проверьте.

Comment: А не проще искать до первого пробела?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Вообще проще, но автор говорит, что ссылка может быть в любом месте, и может случиться так, что текст, скорее всего, может тоже содержать пробелы.

Comment: Я говорю о первом пробеле после начала ссылки

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать используя только explode:

```
$description = "текст https://google.com текст";
$one = explode('https://', $description, 1); // [0]:'текст ' [1]:'google.com текст'
if (empty($one)) {
    echo 'не найдено';
} else {
    $two = explode(' ', $one[1], 1); // [0]:'google.com' [1]:'текст'
    $result = $one[0].'[link]https://'.$two[0].'[/link] '.two[1];
}
```